# How to use a SAS (signed acess signature) for a blob storage hosting a ClickOnce installation?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, clickonce

I would like to host ClickOnce installation files on a non public Azure Blob Storage.
To make it available for my users I created a stored access policy and a SAS (shared access signature) for this policy.
I configured the SAS URL as installation folder URL.
But the installation process appends the name of the .application file after the parameters to the SAS URL. This results in an invalid URL and a broken installation.

Is there a way to use URL parameters in a installation folder URL without creating invalid URL during installation?
Or is there a better way to make a private Azure Blob Storage avaiable to my users?

I already tried some hacks like including the .application file in the URL directly and appending a # at the end to keep the URL valid.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with _the installation process appends the name of the .application file after the parameters_ which I guess is clickonce? Ypou'd be better off if possible to download the file locally then run it from a local location.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid. Hosting the file locally is what I do right now. But I'd like to deploy directly from the Azure DevOps Pipeline, that's why I wanted to use the blob storage.

Comment: I'm talking about storing the file in blob, and just pulling it down locally temporarily for the install process. I don't know where DevOps comes into this. That's a "push" scenario whereas I thought ClickOnce was a user interctive "pull" scenario

Comment: The ClickOnce installation files are created by a DevOps Pipeline and stored in the blob. I don't know how to pull them down for installation and update as ClickOnce handles installation and checking for updates at the given URL (blob).

Comment: Where are the files being applied? On someone’s client machine?

Comment: The files are created by the Pipeline building the solution and consumed by the ClickOnce installer and ClickOnce auto update check on multiple client machines.

Comment: I know very little about clkonce, but does this help? https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/how-to-host-a-clickonce-deployment-in-azure-blob-storage/

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid, I read that one. It covers the main parts. But her installation is public and therefore without a SAS.